# Pré-visualizar Excel, Power Point, Word num site

Tags: html5, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, powerpoint

Bom dia,
Gostava de saber como pré-visualizar Excel, Power Point, Word num site.
Para o Pdf consegui fazer com este código.

```
<embed src="RelatorioM16.pdf" width="760" height="500"></embed>
```

ou

```
<iframe src="RelatorioM16.pdf" width="760" height="500"></iframe>
```

Ao fazer este código para Excel, Power Point, Word no site ele descarrega o ficheiro, coisa que não quero, quero pré-visualizar.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Acho que não é possivel diretamente, teria que printar o documento e mostrar a imagem ou ler e transformar em HTML. Se não me engano tem um formato que já salva como HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O browser não consegue fazer preview de word ou excel a não ser que os teus clientes tenham extensões para isso como o office webapps [OfficeWebApp](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/)

A outra opção é teres componentes de terceiros pagos/free que te fazem isso.

Última opção seres tu a fazer :), é teres no servidor da aplicação web office instalado e colocas um bocado de código que te converte o teu Excel/Word/PowerPoint para PDF ou para HTML.

Espero ter ajudado